# How many times is this function called?

Tags: c++

I have this subalgorithm on recursion and I know that it's called 5 times, but I don't understand why. The initial values are m=1, n=2.

I've thought the function is called for 7 times.

```
int Ack(int m, int n)
{
    if (m==0) 
        return n+1;
    else 
         {
            if (m>0 && n==0) 
                return Ack(m-1,1);
            else 
                return Ack(m-1,Ack(m,n-1));
        }
}
```

I expect that it's called 7 times or even more, but the actual number is 5.

This how 7 is arrived at:

1. Ack(1,2)
2. Ack(0,Ack(1,1))
3. Ack(1,1)
4. Ack(0,Ack(1,0))
5. Ack(1,0)
6. Ack(0,1), a function which returns 2. Ack(0,1)=Ack(1,0)=2 ==>
7. Ack(0,2) (we came back to number 4) = 3
8. Ack(0,3) (we came back to number 2)

Comment: And...have you tried to debug it to compare what really happens with your idea?

Comment: @Ventu 1) Ack(1,2)
2) Ack(0,Ack(1,1))
3) Ack(1,1) 
4) Ack(0,Ack(1,0))
5) Ack(1,0)
6) Ack (0,1), a function which returns 2. 
Ack(0,1)=Ack(1,0)=2 ==> 7) Ack (0,2) (we came back to number 4)  = 3 
8) Ack (0,3) (we came back to number 2)

Comment: @SeverienneBianca, Just add this execution path to your Question and format it properly, it's horrible to read in a comment.

Comment: It's called 6 times: https://tio.run/##bU9BCsMgEDzHV@wpKCporyGFPiWILdK4DWlyCr7dqklJE7qHnR12Ztg1wyBN3@EjRocTmNeceguqISTzm3nSjF5ABmRkIZCK86JsCnF3oL5tFYNCc412mkcE5HqV2P5t9y0s@/j1XxXUNeAx5hSXr/FSC82ag@SU/t9UUKDU7McdSFgf9Z1DytJhVdZpAZekItWWsT0bYvwA

Answer (score 0):

You double-counted 2 calls: #7 is the same as #4, and #8 is the same as #2 (just with the values returned by `Ack` shown): "coming back" isn't the same as calling.